# Naturality of cup product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently reading Spanier AT. I want to prove the following

> Let $f:X\to Y$ map $A_1\mapsto B_1$ and $A_2\mapsto B_2$ and let $u\in H^p(Y,B_1;G)$ and $v\in H^q(Y,B_2;G')$. Let $f_1:(X,A_1)\to (Y,B_1)$, $f_2:(X,A_2)\to (Y,B_2)$, and $\bar{f}:(X,A_1\cup A_2)\to (Y,B_1\cup B_2)$ be maps defined by $f$. In $H^{p+q}(X,A_1\cup A_2;G'')$ we have
> $$\bar{f}^*(u\smile v) = f^*_1u\smile f^*_2v$$

[image: .]

To show the above diagram commutes, here's one fact : If I denote a homomorphism by $\varphi:G\otimes G'\to G''$, then $u\smile v = \varphi_*(d^*(u\times v))$ where $d:X\to X\times X$ is a diagonal map. Hence, $\bar{f}^*(u\smile v) = \bar{f}^*\varphi_*(d^*(u\times v))$ and $f^*_1u\smile f^*_2v = \varphi_*(d^*(f^*_1u\times f^*_2v)) = \varphi_*(d^*(f_1\times f_2)^*(u\times v))$. Hence the above diagram reduced to
[image: ..]

Well how can I say this diagram commutes? I know $\varphi_*$ is funtorial but $d^*$ is just and induced map.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure, maybe I am oversimplifying things, but here is my attempt:

By definition of the cup product on cochains we have:
$$
 (u\smile v)(\sigma_{[p+q]})=u(\sigma_{[p]})\cdot v(\sigma_{[p+1,\ldots,p+q]})\\
u\in C^p(X,A);\; v\in C^q(X,B);\; u\smile v\in C^{p+q}(X,A\cup B);\\
\sigma\in C_{p+q}(X,A+B).
$$
Now an induced map on cochains looks like this:
$$
\overline{f}^*(u\smile v)(\sigma_{[p+q]})=(u\smile v)(\overline{f}\sigma_{[p+q]}).
$$
Applying the formula for the cup product on cochains we get
$$
\overline{f}^*(u\smile v)(\sigma_{[p+q]})=u(\overline{f}\sigma_{[p]})\cdot v(\overline{f}\sigma_{[p+1,\ldots,p+q]})
$$
Now it remains to note that by definition $\overline{f}$ behaves on $\sigma_{[p]}$ like $f_1$ and on $\sigma_{[p+1,\ldots,p+q]}$ like $f_2.$